# AsyncTask onPostExecute выполняется до doinbackground

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Не могу понять, где ошибка, прошу подсказать:

```
private class GetUserObject extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Map<String, Object>> {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        dataService.getFirebaseUsers().child(userPreferences.getUID()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Post = (Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();
                Log.e("userBG ", "background");

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
        return Post;

    }
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
    Log.e("userProgress ", "progress");
}

protected void onPostExecute(Map<String, Object> somemap){
        super.onPostExecute(Post);
        //UserData userData = new UserData(Post);
        Log.e("userPE ", "after loading");
    }
}
```

Смысл в том, что получаю выполнение onPostExecute() до завершения выполнения doInBackground. В логе:

```
04-22 08:24:09.343 E/userPE: after loading
04-22 08:24:09.473 E/userBG: background
```

Comment: покажите, как вы используете ваш `Asynctask`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы повесели слушатели в `dataService.getFirebaseUsers().child.....`. Я не знаю, что это за либа, Возможно по описанию по сути методов это фреймворк базы данных, но тем не менее, вы используете анонимный класс, который по своей функции работает асинхронно, а значит вы можете смело запускать его без асинктаска.. `doInBackground` отработал честно.

```
 dataService.getFirebaseUsers().child(userPreferences.getUID()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Post = (Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();
                UserData userData = new UserData(Post)

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Из официальной документации:

> Firebase data is retrieved by attaching an asynchronous listener to a Firebase reference.

Т.е Ваш `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` асинхронный. Соответственно, выполнение Вашего `AsyncTask` завершилось, а `listener` совсем другая история.